# Issue with Connect-SPOService

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I have to delete one of my SharePoint site but unfortunately I can only do it using PowerShell. However when I try to use the `Connect-SPOService` command, I get this error message:

> Connect-SPOService: The term 'Connect-SPOService' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

So here is what I did:

1 – I installed the latest version of PowerShell from https://aka.ms/powershell-release?tag=stable

Note: My environment is a Windows Server 2016

2 – I installed the SharePoint Online Management Shell using the following command

`Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell`

But I tried to run the `Connect-SPOService` command, I got the error mentioned above.

Now the interesting thing is that when I run:

`Get-Module -ListAvailable *sharepoint*`, I get this

```
Directory: D:\Users\<path of my business OneDrive>\Documents\PowerShell\Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Binary     16.0.2151…            Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerS… Desk
```

Why is the ExportedCommands is empty?

Why did the SharePoint Online Management Shell get installed under my OneDrive path and not under the location where PowerShell 7 got installed which is “C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7”

What can I do so the `Connect-SPOService` command works?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is with the different DLLs in your Global Assembly Cache (GAC). Run this command and check the output:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\*Microsoft.SharePoint*.dll -Recurse | ft Name,@{Label="Version";Expression={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}} -AutoSize
```

If the file versions are different, that's your problem. Remove one and test it.

Check this article for full, detailed instructions: [*The term ‘Connect-SPOService’ is not recognized*](https://www.easy365manager.com/the-term-connect-sposervice-is-not-recognized/).

Comment: I saw the above post before posting my issue. The DLLs have the same version
----                                                             -------
Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Administration.Client.dll      15.0.4420.1017
Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Administration.Client.Intl.dll 15.0.4420.1017
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Local.Resources.dll          15.0.4420.1017

Comment: the dll you posted above are not the correct, you have to check the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dlls.

Comment: See my question above > Why did the SharePoint Online Management Shell get installed under my OneDrive path and not under the location where PowerShell 7 got installed which is “C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7”

Comment: I found this command from your linked article helpful in seeing what version was installed and whether Exported Commands was empty, but it did not help in actually resolving my issue. I had to add `Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell` to my script (with the `-DisableNameChecking` flag to silence 'undiscoverable name' warnings, and since I was using PowerShell 7, I apparently also needed the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` flag, too).